# ASP.NET Button, OnClientClick not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have button with both OnClick and OnClientClick events declared.

There is some specific task that I wish to accomplish before the postback occurs but for some strange reason **OnClientClick is never fired**. I have used it numerous times before and never had this specific issue.

There is something wrong with it, I also tried with adding 'return false' directly to prevent server side processing but postback occurs nevertheless.

I checked whether my form is inside an UpdatePanel but it is not.

```
<cms:CMSButton ID="btnOk" OnClientClick="clientClick()" OnClick="btnOK_Click" runat="server" ButtonStyle="Default"
                    EnableViewState="false"></cms:CMSButton>

$(document).ready(function () {

    function clientClick() {
        console.log("Clicked");
        document.getElementById("<%=spinner.ClientID  %>").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("<%= btnOk.ClientID%>").style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

Also I tried firing the event in this manner, with no luck, so there may be something else going on here:

```
$('#<%=btnOk.ClientID%>').click(function () {
        console.log('clicked');
    });
```

Checked the console but could not find any js errors.

Comment: you can not put `function clientClick() {` inside the `$(document).ready(function () {` Remove it from there and try again. Also right after the click you make post back, so you may not see the console.log, except if you keep the history

Comment: Yes but I should see it for a glimpse at least, until page finishes reloading.
Also I tried returning false directly from OnClientClick to prevent the postback, but postback still occurs.
I removed document.ready but no change.

Comment: do this `OnClientClick="clientClick();return false;"` or `OnClientClick="return clientClick();"` and then return false inside the function

Comment: Tried it already, not working.

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested - avoid document.Ready like the plague.

Now don't take this suggested rule as all or nothing. The simple matter is WHEN you need to use document.ready - then use it, but ALSO when you can avoid using it, don't just out of the blue use it to hook up event code - it REALLY hard to follow.

Now, you posted your markup - I don't know if you left parts out, but again WHEN code is not working, then you want to provide a wee bit more details.

your code should look like this:

```
<cms:CMSButton ID="btnOk" OnClientClick="clientClick()" OnClick="btnOK_Click"
   runat="server" ButtonStyle="Default"
EnableViewState="false"></cms:CMSButton>

  <script>
    function clientClick() {
       console.log("Clicked");
       document.getElementById("<%=spinner.ClientID  %>").style.display = "block";
       document.getElementById("<%= btnOk.ClientID%>").style.display = "none";
    }
 </script>
```

So you have a function, you have a onclick, you have a js function wiht that name. Nice, simple code approach here. Be it code behind, or js code in the page? You write a function, and then specify that function. Keep this simple.

In fact, I often suggest that you put the  RIGHT below the button so you don't have to go trouging around the page to go find that routine in the markup.